Is this host and 'parasite' interaction feasible?
So I have an idea for this relationship between bloodsucking and flesheating creatures and a massive host. It should be noted that this will probably take place in my more alieny world, but basic concepts are still a universal thing.
So basically there is this gargantuan creature that is host to these much smaller parasitic creatures that feed upon the blood and flesh of it.
Now of course, this on a smaller scale happens all the time, but…not this, as far as I know. See, this interaction has them producing a substance or really reverse venom, that they spit or inject into the host to induce better and more complete healing. I am assuming it probably also is saturated in pleasure and pain blocking chemicals.
In return, they will guard, with their lives, this host from predators and attackers big and small. The closest thing I can think of in nature is ants and acacia trees, but still not 1 to 1 match as the ants do not secret healing substances and the titan does not purposely produce parts for the ‘parasites’ to eat.
So is this a feasible interaction between organisms that can be done without having to handwave, at least a ton?

if it's a mutually beneficial interaction it's not called parasitism

Sounds more like symbiosis to me.

the "parasites" need to be eusocial like ants if you want them to die forr their host, killing yourself is never a good way ot protect a resource unless, you are not the carrier of your genes.

It is not parasitism, but symbiosis.  There are many examples of organisms where they live together for mutual advantage, and frequently require living together for survival.
Lichen consists of a fungus and a cyanobacteria or algae.  The fungus, in fact, can't survive without a partner that engages in photosynthesis, while the algae/cyanobacteria can live separately but benefit from the protection of the fungus.

Parasitism IS a symbiotic relationship in most definitions, but yeah, this is a mutualistic relationship type symbiosis.

@ConanHighwoods  Parasitism means that the host is suffering from the relationship. Symbiosis means that both get something out of it. That's the definition of the words, they mean something opposite and parasitism will never be symbiotic.

@Jemox As a technical term, parasitism is a form of symbiosis. What you learn as symbiosis in grade school is mutualism, the type of symbiosis where both parties benefit. There is also commensalism, where one party benefits and the other is neutral. All "symbiosis" means is "living together"

Yes it is feasible:

Leeches pump out analgesics to stop their meal from noticing that they're being chewed on.

The Toxoplasma gondii parasite pumps out pleasure chemicals in the presence of cats to get its intermediate host to get chewed on.

There are also chemicals that induce healing in the hosts own biology and they could be produced en masse by a parasite that was sufficiently adapted to its host.

Any creature will defend their food to some degree, and their feeding grounds, the parasites defending their host to the death is definitely in keeping with this behaviour, especially if the titan is their only host.


I don't see any great degree of handwaving needed here. The only thing that gives me pause is the total regeneration of the host as opposed to the more usual, incomplete healing, i.e. scarring, we're used to seeing but that's no necessarily unheard of either.

the only problem with this scenario is that if the parasites increase the healing rate, this might lead to blood-clots forming i the host's body, due to overproduction of wound-patching platelets triggered by the parasites. This would be especially bad if the creature is very big, and blood would be pooling in its lower extremities. So you need a mechanism to address that.

@zovits Thanks for the edit, weird to have a copy-paste have the wrong spelling.

First of all, there is nothing parasitic about the smaller creatures. The relationship is symbiotic, as the smaller creatures feed on the bigger creature and in exchange they heal him and protect him. If anything should be a parasite, it would be the bigger creature. Is it a fair trade for it to live its life scot-free while the smaller creatures are literally dying for it? Nevertheless, as for whether it is feasible, yes. If the smaller creatures are not affecting the bigger creature’s future, and vice versa, then the symbiotic relationship will last.
